# How to read what is typed in search bar of ReactSelect?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-select

Is there a way to read whatever we type in the search bar of ReactSelect? And keep it as is in the search bar even if don't select anything from the dropdown options.

Comment: If you don't select any option the search value stays in the input. Add more details.

Comment: https://react-select.com/props you can control the search input using `inputValue` and `onInputChange`